# MS Exchange Server2010 - server address?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

We have a small business network with SBS2011 and Exchange2010 setup; the clients are all using Outlook to retrieve their email over the LAN, which works fine.

But there is one apple machine that is also to be connected to the Exchange server that is causing me some trouble.

According to the Windows clients, the exchange server address `sbs2011.frec.local` (Mac is in the same network range and can ping the server)

Is this the right address, or should it be something like `exchange.sbs2011.frec.local`, where can I look this up in the Exchange Management Console?

The mail addresses are linked to the domain user accounts, when I am asked for login data, should I enter the domain-account login or the mail address? (For example: user: `frec/joe.smith` pw: `trustno1` or user: `joe.smith@frec.com` pw: `qwerty`)

The apple runs OSX 10.6.8, which should support the Exchange server mail retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servername is fine (sbs2011.frec.local), you should be able to use Domain logon FREC\Joe.smith. The Password for Domain logon and mail address is the same I hope. You can use the mail address if it's Setup as the UPN of the user.

Also: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: I tried several things, but haven't thought about using the domain login before asking my question here. I'll report if it worked.